# Why Sorting the timestamp using sort_values is not working?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, datetime, timestamp, epoch

I have a column of timestamp converted to human readable form.
I have tried to sort it from epochtime as well as after converting. It's giving me

```
Fri, 08 Feb 2019 17:24:16 IST
Mon, 11 Feb 2019 02:19:40 IST
Sat, 09 Feb 2019 00:22:43 IST
```

which is not sorted.

I have used sort_values()

```
each_tracker_df = each_tracker_df.sort_values(["timestamp"],ascending=True)
```

why it isn't working??

Comment: Okay. But I have a complete dataset. How am i supposed to sort it.

Comment: Yep. it is.
however I thought of sorting them before i convert them into readable format. But any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the time is in **IST**. Replace the string **IST** with **NULL**.

```
>>import datetime
>>times=['Fri, 10 Feb 2010 17:24:16','Fri, 11 Feb 2010 17:24:16','Fri, 11 Feb 2019 17:24:16']
>>change_format=[]
>> for time in times:
         change_format.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
>>change_format.sort()
```